# How to list public folder mailboxes via EWS?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I cannot find any solution to properly list all public folder mailboxes and public folders using SOAP api. I found only powershell commands or C# methods. If anybody know how to get/list all public folders, please provide me with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enumerate Public Folders you need to use the FindFolder operation and then make a Shallow traversal query of each folder level starting at the Root (because you can't do deep traversals) eg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Body>
        <FindFolder Traversal="Shallow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
        <FolderShape>
            <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        </FolderShape>
        <ParentFolderIds>
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="publicfoldersroot"/>
        </ParentFolderIds>
        </FindFolder>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

You can't get Public folder Mailboxes using EWS what you should be doing on Office365 is discovering the correct PublicFolder Mailbox to include in the routing headers so you should read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-content-requests (which both have XML samples for the calls you need).

Comment: Can you give me an example of the request to distinguish correct primary public folder mailbox?

Comment: I did smth like it: 
POST outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
   <Request>
     <EMailAddress>user@test.onmicrosoft.com</EMailAddress>
     <AcceptableResponseSchema>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a</AcceptableResponseSchema>
   </Request>
 </Autodiscover>
and got the response: 500 "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed."
and I do not know what is wrong

Comment: Autodiscover requests need to be sent to the Autodiscover endpoint eg autodiscover-s.outlook.com//autodiscover/autodiscover.xml or /autodiscover/autodiscover.svc depending if its a POX (plain old XML) or SOAP based request

Comment: Thank you, but the response I got from your suggested endpoints is             <ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode>
            <Message>The email address can't be found.</Message>. I am sure that provided email address is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to determine the value of the X-AnchorMailbox header using SOAP and make an Autodiscover request to determine the X-PublicFolderInformation value.

Secondly, use `FindFolder` and then traversal query of each folder level starting at the Root, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindFolder Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </m:FolderShape>
      <m:IndexedPageFolderView MaxEntriesReturned="1" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:Restriction>
        <t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:DisplayName" />
          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
            <t:Constant Value="My Public Contacts" />
          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
        </t:IsEqualTo>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:FolderId Id="AQEuAAADy/LIWjRCp0GFb0W6aGPbwwEARg5aCLUc8k6wLfl1c0a/2AAAAwIAAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAABYAAABGDloItRzyTrAt+XVzRr/YAABdo/XB" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Reference from:

[Route public folder hierarchy requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests)

[Route public folder content requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-content-requests)